# Does a partial derivative existing at a point imply it exists in a neighbourhood of that same point?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

One sufficient condition for a function to be differentiable at a point $a$ is for it to have partial derivatives in $B_{\epsilon}(a)$ and they be continuous.

My question is if having partial derivatives at $a$, implies the existence of an $\epsilon$ where partial derivatives exist everywhere in $B_{\epsilon}(a)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Wiki page

$\;\;\;\;\;\;\,$https://calculus.subwiki.org/wiki/Existence_of_partial_derivatives_not_implies_differentiable

we get the following counterexample . . .

If $f:\mathbb{R^2}\to\mathbb{R}$ is given by $f(x,y)=(xy)^{\large{{\frac{1}{3}}}}$, then

- $f$ is continuous.$\\[4pt]$

  $f_x(0,0)=0$ and $f_y(0,0)=0$.$\\[4pt]$

  $f_x(0,t)$ does not exist if $t\ne 0$.$\\[4pt]$

  $f_y(t,0)$ does not exist if $t\ne 0$.

Comment: Quasi, thanks. By the way, how would one go about to prove the existence of the partial derivatives in a neighbourhood? Is there a simpler way than just using the limit definition?

Comment: It depends on the form by which the function is defined.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the function
$$f(x):=\left\{\eqalign{x^2\qquad&(x\in{\mathbb Q})\cr 0\ \qquad&(x\notin{\mathbb Q})\ .\cr}\right.$$
Then $f'(0)=0$, but $f$ is not  differentiable at any point $x\ne0$.

Comment: Christian thanks for your answer. I still have some doubts, though. If the existence of partial derivatives would imply continuity, then I would understand the importance of f not being continuous. However,  since they do not, why is it important to see f is not continuous for the existence of partial derivatives?